# deleting an excel file in C#, Taskmanager process is not stopped

Tags: excel

I am working on a wpf application.

I am copying the data to excel sheet from database and saving the file and closing it once the operation is completed.

My question is:

How to stop the Process(EXCEL.EXE) in TaskManager->Processes ?

I have to delete the file after the operation is completed. I have written a pieceof code to stop the process in taskmanager, but didnt work..

```
  private void EndExcelAPP(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            obj = null;
        }
    }
```

I cant delete it since using this too.. since it says the process is used by another process.

Please help me how to stop this process programatically in c# and delete the fiile ?

Thanks

Ramm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure you close the workbook and exit the application:

```
Excel.Application xlApp ;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;

/* do your stuff */

xlWorkbook.Close();
xlApp.Exit();

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're not cleaning up after yourself (or more accurately, after Excel).  Check out:

[How to properly clean up Excel interop objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c)

After Excel has stopped running in the background you should be able to delete the file.  And you shouldn't have to write code to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Did you close the workbook before releasing it?  That's what I do and it works for me.  [Here's an example](http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop).